# Tableau 2018: How to replicate this graph (from excel)

Tags: tableau-desktop, yield-return

I need to replicate this graph that has been made using excel in Tableau.
I need to display the # of sales vs the spend p/day and then show the yield curve.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Spend is getting aggregated and can't be showed per day